# Generate Table with only one Column

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i try to generate a table with only one column. So my Links get displayed in only one column.

Here is my function:

```
    function createTableForPdfFiles() {

        //To Create The Table
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute('id', 'pdfTable');
        table.setAttribute('class', 'AANTable');

        // insert Title Row
        var TitleRow = table.insertRow();
        var cell = TitleRow.insertCell(); 
        cell.setAttribute('class', 'AANTitleRow');
        cell.setAttribute('colSpan', pdfFiles.length + 1);
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Datenblätter"));

        //Insert Table Rows
        var pdfRow = table.insertRow();
        var cell = pdfRow.insertCell(); //Where the PDF´s are displayed
        cell.setAttribute('class', 'AANPdfRow');

        for (var i = 0; i < pdfFiles.length; i++) {
            var cell = pdfRow.insertCell();
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", "www.test.at" + pdfFiles[i].Link);
            var linktext = document.createTextNode(pdfFiles[i].Link);
            link.appendChild(linktext);
            cell.appendChild(link);
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'AANPdfCell');

        }

        $("#divTable").append(table);
}
```

Right now it looks like:
[image: Wrong Table]

But i want it to look like:
[image: good Table]

So how i can i make that possibe? I tried to add another Row to the table but the debugger says not supported...... Any help would be really great.

thanks for your Time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create anew row foer each pdf.

Hae to put this

```
var pdfRow = table.insertRow();
var cell = pdfRow.insertCell(); //Where the PDF´s are displayed
cell.setAttribute('class', 'AANPdfRow');
```

Inside the for

take a look at this -> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/1x4v7fq7/)

Comment: just copy and paste it from the fiddle and it works like a blast.